# How do I create a React Native CLI project with Java instead of Kotlin

Tags: react-native

I want that the MainActivity file and others are based only on Java, but it's generating Kotlin by default.

If I create it using expo it generate Java files, but I'd like to use React Native CLI.

Comment: As of react native 73 the files are built with java instead of kotlin [(see here)](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/12/06/0.73-debugging-improvements-stable-symlinks#kotlin-template-on-android). I have seen it suggested to provide an install template to override this, although I do not know if it will actually work. If it fails and you do not need to use react native 73, you could just use react native 72

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well and looking for solution too. just curious, why they put the kotlin codes under java folder of native files? its very misleading.

Comment: nevermind. I just discovered that kotlin are adaptable to java codes so I was able to apply the same syntax in my app